# WCF webservice seems to be going in an infinite loop

Tags: wcf, infinite-loop, wcf-binding

I have a web service I have created and I am calling a method inside it and logging to a text file. It seems to be re-starting this method for an infinite number of times as it keeps logging the same line. I suspect it could be something in my config file that is wrong, can someone veryfy the bindings etc pls?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>

  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TLS_Service.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TLS_Service.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime" publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From your code snippets, I could see any obvious fault. It seems that you want to publish the web service via http mode.
If you want to accept the server error on client side, you could change the CustomErrors mode to On. What are the error details of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seemed to be: lack of RAM on the server / too many ExecuteQuery requests in the Web Service Code.